# Warning: session_encode(): Cannot encode non-existent session in site (Have started Session)

Tags: php, session

I have the following code in a php file (Logit.php) and I call the logging function below from it:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

function logging($string){
// Other stuff
    $SESSIONData = session_encode(); // Field Length: 8192
// Other stuff
}
```

The php file that includes this logging script is running as a cron job and sometimes I run it at the command line.  I get the following error in my Apache logs:

> Warning: session_encode(): Cannot encode non-existent session in
> /var/www/example.com/Logit.php

Any thoughts on why, and how can I remove this error?  Information related to this error is very sparse and doesn't address this issue.  I got only three hits on SO that were even remotely related.

Comment: _Why_ would you be using a session in a script that gets executed via cron?

Comment: CRON jobs get executed by the CLI and there is no SESSION in the CLI

Comment: @CBroe because it is also used in regular Webserver based scripts on the same site.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php), `session_status()` might return `PHP_SESSION_DISABLED` if sessions are disabled (which is likely for non-webserver scripts, as in your case). If your script is run in an environment with sessions disabled, this is exactly the behaviour you would get. `session_start` isn't called because `session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE` is false (so you don't get an error there), and `session_encode()` is called without a session (which can't exist anyway because they are disabled), resulting in an error

Comment: Is there any way to trap that condition (running in a cron or via CLI)?

Comment: @Chiwda Just add another check for `session_status() === PHP_SESSION_DISABLED`